# Parallel.ForEach + missing records

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

I have the below function which does a set of tasks:

```
private async Task DoworkAsync(List<OrderFragment> of)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var task = CreateOrderjson(of);
    await task;
    var task1 = GetBearerToken();
    await task1;
    var task2 = SubmitOrderIntake(task.Result, task1.Result);
    task2.Wait();    
    var task3 = createExcel();
    await task3;
}

private async Task<List<string>> CreateOrderjson(List<OrderFragment> of)
{

}

private static async Task<string> GetBearerToken()
{

}
```

Third method:

```
private async Task<string[]> SubmitOrderIntake(List<string> orderJson, string result)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(orderJson, async order =>
    {
        orederResult = await PostOrderintake(order, result);
    });

    return customerArray;
}

private async Task<ConcurrentBag<string>> PostOrderintake(string order, string result)
{

}
```

I have two issues:

1. There is always a missing item in the response vs requests. I tried all solution
   mentioned but missing keeps happening
2. `var task3 =  createExcel();` This is executing before `SubmitOrderIntake`. This function need to be called last.

Comment: Use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` instead of `Parallel.ForEach`. `ForEach` is only meant for data parallelism: processing lots of in-memory data using all cores

Comment: Thanks . I think oreachasync is available from .net5 but we run on 4.5 in all user machine . It did anwer my question .

Comment: 4.5 went out of support in 2016. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. There are other ways to do whatever you want, eg using TransformBlock and ActionBlock to build a pipeline of individual steps. `DoWorkAsync` is buggy anyway. `await` already returns the result of the operation, so there's no reason to have `await task1;` and then pass the result with `task1.Result`